# SQL Server database connection using System DSN in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am a .NET developer using C#. I have configured DSN in my machine of remote SQL Server database. I have provided database name, user name and password while System DSN creation. I am trying to connect to that database in our Windows based application using DSN but doesn't want to provide user name and password because I have already defined in DSN but unable to connect.

Application throws an error

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.

When I provide DB user name and password along with DSN in connection string then it works but I don't want to give DB user name and password again.

My sample code:

```
 string connString = "Dsn=TMagic";

    OdbcConnection OdbcConn = new OdbcConnection(connString);

    //open connection 
    if (OdbcConn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
          OdbcConn.Open();
    }

    string sqlQuery = "select * from userinfo";
    DataSet dataSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
    OdbcDataAdapter dataAdapter =    new OdbcDataAdapter(sqlQuery, OdbcConn);
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
    dataAdapter.Dispose();
    dataAdapter = null;
```

Please let me how to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I really can't understand why a *local* connection variable, just created need to be tested for its connectionstate.

Comment: How to solve this? Use the **native** SQL client libraries - `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` etc - instead of ODBC

Comment: Can you share the details of DSN. If you dont want to use SQL Authentication then using Windows authentication, should make sure that the user is provided access in database. It is recommended to use SQLClient rather than ODBC for C# .